# Search for sites exclude team sites sharepoint online 2013

Tags: sharepoint-online, search

In query Transform 
{SearchTerms} (contentclass: "STS_web")
how to set a filter that it will exclude all the team sites.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do it:

```
{SearchTerms} (contentclass: "STS_web") AND NOT WebTemplate:STS
```